# Laravel and vue router

Tags: laravel, vue.js, eloquent

I am new to using Vue as a frontend and Laravel has a backend.

I have 2 related models that are namely a Users model and a Posts model.
Users can have many posts and a post belongs to one user.

I can retrieve the Posts but I want to click on a User on users page and get a list the related users's Posts.

Using axios to get related User Posts lists with the following in Users vue

This is the link I use to open the Posts page.

```html
<v-btn @click="$router.push({ name:'posts.list', params:{ id:item.id } })" 
       class="ma-0" 
       outlined 
       fab 
       small 
       color="success" 
       title="View Posts">
    <v-icon>mdi-tray-full</v-icon>
</v-btn>
```

```js
axios.get('/admin/posts/' + self.propUserId, { params: params })
    .then(function(response) { 
        self.items = response.data.data.data; 
        self.totalItems = response.data.total; 
        self.pagination.totalItems = response.data.total; 
        (cb || Function)(); 
    });
```

I am trying to pass the User Id to the router js through self.propUserId

```
path: '/:id',
name: 'posts.list',
component: require('./posts/components/PostLists'),
props: (route) => ({propUserId: route.params.id}),
```

I have the following router in the web router within the

```php
Route::prefix('admin')
    ->namespace('Admin')
    ->middleware(['auth'])
    ->group(function() { 
        Route::resource('posts/{id}','PostController');
        // .....
    });
```

I am however getting all Posts without the condition being applied.I only want is all Posts that belong to the clicked User.The Foreign column related to Users table in the Posts table is user_id.

Comment: Can we see you'r controller code?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting up the inverse relationship at the Post-Model correctly?

It should be something like:

```
// Post.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. 

// Post.php
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}